# SQL Server updating new column based on another column from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my situation:

**Hint**: COLUMN (NUMBER_IDENTITY) on 2 tables have the same value but those 2 table have no relationship with each other (this is my choice for my situation)

**Early database state**

- I had table `CONTRACTS` (ID, NUMBER_IDENTITY, USER_ID)
- I had table `SUB_CONTRACTS` (ID, NUMBER_IDENTITY)

**NOW**

I have table `CONTRACTS` (ID, NUMBER_IDENTITY, USER_ID)

I add new column in `SUB_CONTRACTS` (ID, NUMBER_IDENTITY, USER_ID)

**My problem**

I should update `USER_ID` column in `SUB_CONTRACTS` with the same value that exists in `CONTRACTS`. I can do this update because `NUMBER_IDENTITY` column of the two tables is the same. So `SUB_CONTRACT` is complementary of `CONTRACT`.

**Question**

How to build a function, procedure or query in SQL Server that will solve my problem? Can I make a function that update in the same time all the column that meets this condition? I can solve in mini solution with query but I can't join all this mini query to solve my problem.

Comment: Free hand, but a simple update+join a'la `UPDATE sc SET sc.user_id=c.user_id FROM sub_contracts sc JOIN contracts c ON sc.number_identity=c.number_identity` should do it. Question is though, why are you storing the user id in an extra place if it's always supposed to be the same as on the contract?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Because i should keep some information of sub_contracts in diffrent table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update SUB_CONTRACTS
set USER_ID = CONTRACTS.USER_ID
from SUB_CONTRACTS
inner join CONTRACTS on (SUB_CONTRACTS.NUMBER_IDENTITY = CONTRACTS.NUMBER_IDENTITY)
```

This syntax will work for SQL Server. It will update all `USER_ID` values in `SUB_CONTRACTS` to match the `USER_ID` values in `CONTRACTS` where the `NUMBER_IDENTITY` value is the same in the two tables.